# Select observations using variables from a second data set

Tags: sas, dataset

I have two datasets in SAS. They both contain the same variable `x`. In the first data set, I want to remove those observations whose `x` value is also in the `x` values in the second data set.

Example,

```
data set1;
    input x y z;
    datalines;
    1 1.5 2.2
    1 2.1 9.0
    2 4.2 4.4
    3 4.5 2.4
    ;
run;

data set2;
    input x y;
    datalines;
    1 15
    2 44
    ;
run;
```

In set 1, I want to remove those observations if `x=1` or `x=2` where 1 and 2 come from the `x` values from second data set. I only want to keep the last row in set 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your final answer should only include the 3? There are a few ways, but I find this the clearest method for understanding.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select * 
from set1
where x not in (select x from set2);
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Data step version:

```
data want;
  merge set1(in = _1) 
        set2(in = _2 keep = x);
  by x;
  if _1 and not(_2);
run;
```

This assumes that set1 and set2 have both either been sorted by x or have an index on x.